# Использование двух полей short вместо uint для хранения HiWord/LoWord

Tags: c#, winapi, выравнивание, pinvoke, типизация

Можно ли использовать два поля short вместо uint, чтобы самостоятельно не вычислять HiWord/LoWord?

Для примера, я использую [SetWindowsHookEx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexW) (WH_MOUSE_LL), в колбеке [LowLevelMouseProc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)) я получаю структуру [MSLLHOOKSTRUCT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msllhookstruct?redirectedfrom=MSDN) в этой структуре есть поле `DWORD mouseData` у которого старшее слово хранит определенное значение для некоторых сообщений, а младшее зарезервировано.
Можно ли разделять его на 2 short?

Мое объявление структуры на C# выглядит так:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TagMSLLHOOKSTRUCT
{
    public TagPOINT pt;
    public short reserved;
    public short mouseData;
    public uint flags;
    public uint time;
    public UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TagPOINT
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

Это работает, но нет ли у этого подхода минусов/подводных камней?
Можно ли так делать?

Если следовать документации [MSLLHOOKSTRUCT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msllhookstruct?redirectedfrom=MSDN) должно быть так:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TagMSLLHOOKSTRUCT
{
    public TagPOINT pt;
    public uint mouseData;
    public uint flags;
    public uint time;
    public UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}
```

Comment: А вы попробуйте, если заработает, значит можно, только `ushort`.

Comment: @aepot Я написал о том что пробовал и это работает. Но мне нужен ответ который объяснит почему Microsoft не сделала так изначально.

Comment: @aepot Нет, ushort не подойдет, для сообщения WM_MOUSEWHEEL, хранится значение со знаком для указания направления повота колесика мыши.

Comment: Ну наверное у них были какие-то мысли по поводу будущего развития API и использования поля `reserved`, но это по воле звёзд не произошло. Так что если работает, можете спокойно использовать то, что написали. Я вам больше скажу, ваш подход очень правильный и логичный.

Comment: _the high-order word of this member is the wheel delta. The low-order word is reserved_ - в вопросе `reserved` и `mouseData` точно местами не перепутаны? Я просто не помню, какой формат у DWORD в памяти, хотя оно может в управляемую структуру как-то по-своемку маршалируется.

Comment: Да меня тоже смущает порядок заполнения структуры, и сперва по логике я попробовал
`public short mouseData;
public short reserved;`

Но заработало только в том варианте что я выложил.

Comment: Кстати, наткнулся, пока гуглил, советуют использовать [`Raw Input`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) вместо хука. Просто как вариант.

Comment: Тут вопрос не в хуке, он просто для примера, я просто несколько раз сталкивался с тем что значения в структуре хранят LoWord/HiWord и не знаю почему их просто не разделяют

Comment: @user425737 а не в порядке-ли байт дело случайно, поэтому поля местами поменяны? Байты DWORD в little-endian, скорее всего?

Comment: Есть версия, что данные падают из 64-битного регистра процессора (типа `rax`, `rbx` или `rcx`), и ради производительности их записывают в память "как есть".